# How to access file in android internal storage for unity app?

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine

I am using EasyMovieTexture plugin and I want to get access to android folder where all the videos are saved. First I tried to access the streaming asset folder but it is not accessible in the app ([Copying files into asset folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430895/copying-files-into-asset-folder-in-android)) so I have created folder in which all the videos are and I want to access that particular folder to play the videos individually. Here is a sample code which loads the video from url but I want it to access it from storage -

```
void OnGUI() {


    if( GUI.Button(new Rect(50,50,100,100),"Load"))
    {
        scrMedia.Load("Url of video");
        m_bFinish = false;
    }
```

how to access the videos in interval storage to play them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an simple solution for this? I'm trying to do just the same thing :)
I see your comment using the /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.app/cache/ebd_tmp/123.mp4 file path. Assuming 'ebd_tmp' is a folder you've created yourself in the root of your UNity project's Asset folder?

Seems a bit hidden away... is there a way of pointing to a sensible folder on a user's device i.e. 'Videos' or 'Downloads' ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any files in a `StreamingAssets` folder will be included in your build, accessible at the path specified by `Application.streamingAssetsPath`.

However, the manual mentions an important caveat for Android:

> On Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar file (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to retrieve the file, you need to use additional software to see inside the .jar archive and obtain the file.

If your video plugin can access the file within an APK, then you'll just need to specify the correct path.

If your video plugin expects a conventional file, then you will need to create one. Unity's `WWW` class can read the compressed file into memory, which you could then write to some other location (such as `Application.temporaryCachePath`) with `System.File.WriteAllBytes`.

Comment: saved the file in directory in -/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.app/cache/ebd_tmp/- and still getting error on debugging - Error m_MediaPlayer.setDataSource() : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.app/cache/ebd_tmp/123.mp4
System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.app/cache/ebd_tmp/123.mp4

Comment: the file is there but it cannot read it.. what am I doing wrong

Comment: Nvm got it just need to add "file://" before .. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use Application.persistentDataPath to access internal storage.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html

You can see which directory it is using

```
Debug.log(Application.persistentDataPath)
```

Comment: The directory specified by `Application.persistentDataPath` is normally empty unless the Unity application writes something to it (such as save files). Based on that, the video file is only going to be there if something puts it there.

Comment: @rutter I thought of the same and I tried to use Application.temporaryCachePath and stored the files there in the running app but cannot access them

Comment: Yes the directory is empty. I used to save my EasyMovieTexture videos there using AndroidFileTransfer for access in the application.